# how can i hide the names of ancestors of a node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter, circle-pack

I am new to d3 and im trying to represent a codemodel with d3 circle packing. The problem is that there are too many classes and interfaces and the labels of the circles are hard to read.
I figured out that I may need to hide the name of the parent node to make things more clear like this:

```
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(root.descendants())
    .join("circle")
    .on("mouseover", d =>{
      //hide the label of the parent of the node
         var parentNodeLabel = label.filter((e) =>{

            return e == d.parent;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", "0")
        })
     }
```

it works as intended, but then I realized that hiding the name only of the parent doesn't really do much, so now I am trying to hide the names of all ancestors. I tried like this:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        var ancestorNodeLabels = label.filter((e) =>{
            return e == d.ancestors().slice(1);
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", "0")
        })
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work at all. I need tips on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, I am just stupid. I need to check if e is included in the ancestors not to assign it to them.

```
var ancestorNodeLabels = label.filter((e) =>{
            return (d.ancestors().slice(1)).includes(e);
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", "0")
```